# In Jenkins, how can I manually check the signature of plugin updates?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, signature

In Jenkins -> Manage Plugins, I observe this message:

> There were errors checking the update sites: None of the tool installer metadata passed the signature check

My question is: How can I manually check the signature of updates in order to determine if they are valid?

Subsidiary question, how can I determine the cause of this error?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000494608-Why-is-there-Failed-Signature-Check-when-using-update-server-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: In the meantime it seems the expired cert has been renewed:

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/updates/hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.json.html

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 3735928570 (0xdeadbefa)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=San Jose, O=Jenkins Project, CN=Kohsuke Kawaguchi/emailAddress=kk@kohsuke.org
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 19 21:21:39 2018 GMT
            Not After : Nov 19 21:21:39 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, O=Jenkins Project, CN=Community Update Center
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

So for me the issue seems solved.

Comment: Yes, it was probably just because of the update server certificate.

Comment: It seems to be working again. The certificate now has `Not Before: Oct 22 15:09:02 2019 GMT` and `Not After : Oct 21 15:09:02 2020 GMT` set under `Validity`.

Just in case it's not obvious where this is from: see JSON in page source, under `.signature.certificates[0]`; this base64-decodes to DER format.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :
[Why is there Failed Signature Check when using update server?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000494608-Why-is-there-Failed-Signature-Check-when-using-update-server-)

Suppress the signature verification check by adding the following Java option

```
-Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true
```

or

Modify your JDK security policy to admit unsecure encryption algorithms by replacing `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize` < 1024 with `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize` < 512 in the file $JRE_HOME/lib/securityjava.security